# Symfony2 Form Builder custom unmapped field constraint

Tags: php, symfony, formbuilder

I am simply trying to add an email constraint to the unmapped field below and for some reason in the controller action it isn't picking it up. Is there something else I need to be doing?

Form Class

```
/**
 * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
 * @param array $options
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('name', null, [
        'label' => false,
        'attr' => ['placeholder' => 'Name*']
    ]);

    $builder->add('email', null, [
        'mapped' => false,
        'label' => false,
        'attr' => ['placeholder' => 'Email*'],
        'constraints' => [
            new Email(["message" => "Please enter a valid Email Address"])
        ]
    ]);
}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'Test\AppBundle\Entity\Feedback',
        'cascade_validation' => true,
        'validation_groups' => function(Form $form)
        {
            $feedback = $form->getData(); /** @var Feedback $feedback */
            if ($feedback->getType() == Feedback::Type_Feedback)
                return Feedback::ValidationGroup_Feedback;
            else if ($feedback->getType() == Feedback::Type_Link)
                return Feedback::ValidationGroup_Link;

            throw new \Exception("Couldn't generate a valid Validation Group for FeedbackForm.php");
        },
    ));
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getName()
{
    return 'site_feedback_form';
}
```

Controller action

```
public function feedbackSiteSubmitAction(Request $request)
{
    // The form award
    $feedback = new Feedback();

    // Create the form so we can bind send form values to it
    $form = $this->createNewFeedbackForm($feedback);

    // Bind form values
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    // Save
    if ($form->isValid())
    {
        // Add the submission to a member
        $email = $form->get('email')->getData();
        $email = strtolower($email);
        $member = $this->getMemberRepository()->loadByEmail($email);
        if (!$member)
            $member = $this->generateNewPersistedMember($email);

        // Update the mail property
        $member->setReceiveEmail(!$form->get('dontReceiveAlerts')->getData());

        // Add the feedback to the member
        $feedback->setMember($member);

        // Persist the Feedback
        $this->getEntityManager()->persist($feedback);

        // Commit
        $this->getEntityManager()->flush();

        // Response
        return $this->jsonSuccess([
            'html' => $this->renderView('TestAppBundle:Site/partials:feedback_form_success.html.twig', [
                'typeString' => $feedback->getType() == Feedback::Type_Feedback ? "Feedback" : "Resource suggestion"
            ])
        ]);
    }

    // Return errors
    return $this->jsonError($this->getAllFormErrors($form));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In Symfony 2.8 upwards you do the following:

```
$builder->add('email', Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\EmailType::class);
```

Versions before that use:

```
$builder->add('email', 'email');
```

Then you add all your validation criteria via annotations in your `Feedback` class. See the options for `EmailType` [here](http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/reference/forms/types/email.html).

Comment: an `unmaped` field is not in Feedback Class